# Cloud Foundry upload error

Tags: cloud-foundry, jhipster

When I try:

```
CloudFoundry configuration is starting
? Name to deploy as: mobilemanagerdf
? Which profile would you like to use? prod
? What is the name of your database service? cleardb
? What is the name of your database plan? spark
```

I have as response

```
FAILED
Error uploading application.
Server error, status code: 500, error code: 10001, message: An unknown error occurred.

✖ { [Error: Command failed: ] killed: false, code: 1, signal: null }
```

What could be a reson, did you have an similar problem? I'm using Fedora 22, and I have configured CF CLI

Comment: Can you instead try the command `CF_TRACE=true cf push mobilemanagerdf`.  This will drop down a level directly to the `cf`command to remove one layer of indirection, and will give full trace output of the request-response cycle so we can see where the failure is.  Make sure you run the command from the root directory of your application.

Comment: I had succeeded with cf console to deploy, it seems that *.war part does not work properly